# C# - How do I read and write a binary file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, filestream, binaryfiles

How do I read a raw byte array from any file, and write that byte array back into a new file?

Comment: Encoding & BinaryWriter? Encoding is a "string" thingy. You shouldn't have a problem when you are dealing with binary data.

Comment: Jeremy, do you mean "depending on the file type the *format* varies..." ? if the code you're using tries to read/write files with the wrong file type/format I'm sure there would be corruption.

Comment: Reading a file as a `byte[]` is not necessarily a good idea; this could be **very** expensive for large files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(edit: note that the question changed; it didn't mention `byte[]` initially; see [revision  1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2e2ffb6b-b944-4c97-8400-5965f97863f9/view-source))

Well, `File.Copy` leaps to mind; but otherwise this sounds like a `Stream` scenario:

```
    using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(inPath))
    using (Stream dest = File.Create(outPath)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // pick size
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path1);
File.WriteAllBytes(path2, data);
```

Comment: Note that for large files that could be *very* expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) and [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx), and their descendents [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)? I think these will solve your problem because they handle encodings, BinaryReader does not know about encodings or even text, it is only concerned with bytes.

[How to read text from a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

[How to write text to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)

[This is an excellent intro to file IO and encodings.](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive147.html)

Comment: Jeremy asked about reading and writing BINARY files, didn't he?

Comment: If it is just binary data, then why is there any problem with the char encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an up to date answer,

```
using (var source = File.OpenRead(inPath))
{
    using (var dest = File.Create(outPath))
    {
        source.CopyTo(dest);
    }
}
```

you can optionally specify the buffer size

```
using (var source = File.OpenRead(inPath))
{
    using (var dest = File.Create(outPath))
    {
        source.CopyTo(dest, 2048); // or something bigger.
    }
}
```

or you could perform the operation on another thread,

```
using (var source = File.OpenRead(inPath))
{
    using (var dest = File.Create(outPath))
    {
        await source.CopyToAsync(dest);
    }
}
```

which would be useful when the main thread has to do other work, like with WPF and Windows Store apps.