# VB - How do I read and write a binary file?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, filestream, binaryfiles

How do I read a raw byte array from any file...

```
 Dim bytes() as Byte
```

..and then write that byte array back into a new file?

I need it as a byte array to do some processing in between.

---

I'm currently using:

To read

```
 Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(dataPath)
 Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
 Dim fs As New FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
 Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
 Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
 br.Close()
 fs.Close()
```

To write

```
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
fs = New System.IO.FileStream(outpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
fs.Close()
```

Comment: how about you post your attempt?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450542/c-how-do-i-read-and-write-a-binary-file ... but different since C# can do things that VB.NET can't.

Comment: "C# can do things that VB.NET can't" - care to name some, other than some aspects of XML handling?

Comment: @Jeremy: I can't think of any differences in the languages which are relevant to the question.

Comment: LINQ support since I'm targeting NET 2.0?

Comment: You can't use the unsafe keyword in VB, AFAIK.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Dim data() as Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(path1)
File.WriteAllBytes(path2, data)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
Dim bytes() as Byte
bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)
'' # Do stuff to the array
File.WriteAllBytes(otherFileName, bytes)
```