# Getting Pitch with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, audio, mp3, wav

I want to get the pitch of a song at any point.  I plan on storing the pitches later.  How can I read say... an mp3 file or wav file to get the pitch played at a certain point?

Here is a visual example:
[image]
Say I wanted to get the pitch that is here at ^this point of the song.

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matter is a tad more complicated than you may be anticipating.

While time-domain approaches exist (that is, approaches which work with the PCM data directly), frequency-domain pitch detection is going to be more accurate.  You can read a very simplified overview [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm).

What you probably want is a [Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), which can be used to transform blocks of your signal from time-domain to frequency-domain (that is, a distribution of frequency content over a given span of the signal).  From there, you would need to analyze the frequency spectrum within that block.  The problem becomes even harder still, because there is no *best* way to deduce pitch from a sampled frequency spectrum in the general case.  The aforementioned Wikipedia article should give you a foundation for looking into those algorithms.

Finally, it's worth noting that this is really a language-agnostic question, unless your primary interest is in [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450568/vb-how-do-i-read-and-write-a-binary-file) a [WAV file](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) specifically using VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I'll take a look at this once I get home :)

Comment: I use the **BASS** audio library to do a frequency domain transformation and then calculating the pitch. I use it to calculate an accousting fingerprint of any song.